# Unable to get line drawn in class

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouse

The idea is to draw rectangles when the mouse is clicked.  At the moment I am just trying to get some output in the window, nothing is appearing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MouseRectangle extends JPanel {
    

    int xin;
    int yin;    
    MouseRectangle(int x, int y){
        xin = x;
        yin = y;
    }
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
            g.drawLine(100,100,400,400);
            repaint();
            }}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. The code you showed us is certainly not all your code, and is insufficient to try to reproduce the problem. How are you using the `MouseRectangle` class, for example?

Comment: Well I will be using it to fill a rectangle in a grid, to simulate a "life" program.  So I will use the xin and yin variables, there will be no output from the class.

Comment: Well, if you *will be using* it, that means you are not using it yet. So what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I will use the xin and yin variables to fill a square on a grid.  The coordinates will be used to fill an array but that will be in another method

Comment: Again, your use of the future tense tells me you are not yet using the code you showed us. Please provide a [mre] and clearly state why that [mre] does not work (i.e. what your expected behaviour/output is, and what the behaviour/output you actually get is).